# Error "set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set"

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-11, postgresql-13

I have sql script which runs correctly on postgres 11.3 but not on 13.4

I have about 5 tables, used in script - code below

```
SELECT "enterprise_workplace"."id",
       "enterprise_workplace"."created",
       "enterprise_workplace"."modified",
       "enterprise_workplace"."is_active",
       "enterprise_workplace"."safe_deleted_by_id",
       "enterprise_workplace"."safe_deleted_at",
       "enterprise_workplace"."owner_id",
       "enterprise_workplace"."created_by_id",
       "enterprise_workplace"."updated_by_id",
       "enterprise_workplace"."name",
       "enterprise_workplace"."number",
       "enterprise_workplace"."profession_name",
       "enterprise_workplace"."profession_code",
       "enterprise_workplace"."profession_id",
       "enterprise_workplace"."subunit_id",
       "enterprise_workplace"."project_id",
       "enterprise_workplace"."description",
       "enterprise_workplace"."increased_wage",
       "enterprise_workplace"."payed_vacation",
       "enterprise_workplace"."free_milk",
       "enterprise_workplace"."early_retirement",
       "enterprise_workplace"."half_day",
       "enterprise_workplace"."week_length",
       "enterprise_workplace"."medical_inspection",
       "enterprise_workplace"."sout_status",
       "enterprise_workplace"."sout_required",
       "enterprise_workplace"."sout_required_comment",
       "enterprise_workplace"."is_template",
       "enterprise_workplace"."template_id",
       "enterprise_workplace"."staff_position_id",
       "enterprise_workplace"."night_shift",
       "enterprise_workplace"."health_food",
       "enterprise_workplace"."shift_duration",
       "enterprise_workplace"."condition_class",
       "enterprise_workplace"."workplace_status",
       "enterprise_workplace"."workplace_status_comment",
       "enterprise_workplace"."surcharge",
       "enterprise_workplace"."extra_vacation",
       "enterprise_workplace"."occupational_disease",
       "enterprise_workplace"."medical_inspection_period",
       "enterprise_workplace"."preferential_pension_provision",
       "enterprise_workplace"."card_number",
       "enterprise_workplace"."sanitary_standard",
       "enterprise_workplace"."pregnant_woman",
       "enterprise_workplace"."link_id",
       "enterprise_workplace"."similar_to_id",
       "enterprise_workplace"."metadata",
       "enterprise_workplace"."latest_risk_project_id",
       "enterprise_workplace"."latest_sout_report_id",
       "classifier_profession"."id",
       "classifier_profession"."created",
       "classifier_profession"."modified",
       "classifier_profession"."is_active",
       "classifier_profession"."safe_deleted_by_id",
       "classifier_profession"."safe_deleted_at",
       "classifier_profession"."owner_id",
       "classifier_profession"."created_by_id",
       "classifier_profession"."updated_by_id",
       "classifier_profession"."code",
       "classifier_profession"."category_id",
       "classifier_profession"."name",
       "classifier_profession"."short_name",
       "classifier_profession"."function",
       "classifier_profession"."control_number",
       "classifier_profession"."work_level",
       "classifier_profession"."wage_rate_book_original",
       "classifier_profession"."occupation",
       "classifier_profession"."paragraph",
       "classifier_profession"."start",
       "classifier_profession"."end",
       "classifier_profession"."is_feminine",
       "classifier_profession"."genitive_name",
       "classifier_profession"."inspection_required",
       "classifier_profession"."classifier_id",
       "classifier_profession"."readonly",
       "classifier_profession"."cabinet_id",
       "enterprise_subunit"."id",
       "enterprise_subunit"."created",
       "enterprise_subunit"."modified",
       "enterprise_subunit"."is_active",
       "enterprise_subunit"."safe_deleted_by_id",
       "enterprise_subunit"."safe_deleted_at",
       "enterprise_subunit"."owner_id",
       "enterprise_subunit"."created_by_id",
       "enterprise_subunit"."updated_by_id",
       "enterprise_subunit"."name",
       "enterprise_subunit"."short_title",
       "enterprise_subunit"."address",
       "enterprise_subunit"."order",
       "enterprise_subunit"."parent_id",
       "enterprise_subunit"."organization_id",
       "enterprise_subunit"."oktmo",
       "enterprise_subunit"."chief_name",
       "enterprise_subunit"."c1_id",
       "enterprise_subunit"."subunit_head_id",
       "enterprise_subunit"."removed",
       "enterprise_subunit"."date_removed",
       "enterprise_organization"."id",
       "enterprise_organization"."created",
       "enterprise_organization"."modified",
       "enterprise_organization"."is_active",
       "enterprise_organization"."safe_deleted_by_id",
       "enterprise_organization"."safe_deleted_at",
       "enterprise_organization"."owner_id",
       "enterprise_organization"."created_by_id",
       "enterprise_organization"."updated_by_id",
       "enterprise_organization"."name",
       "enterprise_organization"."ogrn",
       "enterprise_organization"."inn",
       "enterprise_organization"."kpp",
       "enterprise_organization"."okpo",
       "enterprise_organization"."okogu",
       "enterprise_organization"."okato",
       "enterprise_organization"."oktmo",
       "enterprise_organization"."address_de_jure",
       "enterprise_organization"."address_postal",
       "enterprise_organization"."director_name",
       "enterprise_organization"."cabinet_id",
       "enterprise_organization"."parent_organization_id",
       "enterprise_organization"."okved_primary_id",
       "enterprise_organization"."main_email_id",
       "enterprise_organization"."main_fax_id",
       "enterprise_organization"."main_phone_id",
       "enterprise_project"."id",
       "enterprise_project"."created",
       "enterprise_project"."modified",
       "enterprise_project"."is_active",
       "enterprise_project"."safe_deleted_by_id",
       "enterprise_project"."safe_deleted_at",
       "enterprise_project"."owner_id",
       "enterprise_project"."created_by_id",
       "enterprise_project"."updated_by_id",
       "enterprise_project"."name",
       "enterprise_project"."description",
       "enterprise_project"."cabinet_id",
       "enterprise_project"."project_type",
       "enterprise_project"."organization_id",
       "enterprise_project"."is_template",
       "enterprise_project"."start",
       "enterprise_project"."end",
       "enterprise_project"."cause",
       "enterprise_project"."responsible_id",
       "enterprise_project"."organization_object_id",
       "enterprise_project"."author_id",
       "enterprise_project"."status",
       "enterprise_project"."workgroup_id",
       "enterprise_project"."department_id",
       "enterprise_project"."plan_start",
       "enterprise_project"."plan_end",
       "enterprise_project"."comment",
       "enterprise_project"."report_document_id",
       "enterprise_project"."assessment_date",
       "enterprise_project"."identified_hazards_and_risks_report_id",
       T6."id",
       T6."created",
       T6."modified",
       T6."is_active",
       T6."safe_deleted_by_id",
       T6."safe_deleted_at",
       T6."owner_id",
       T6."created_by_id",
       T6."updated_by_id",
       T6."name",
       T6."number",
       T6."profession_name",
       T6."profession_code",
       T6."profession_id",
       T6."subunit_id",
       T6."project_id",
       T6."description",
       T6."increased_wage",
       T6."payed_vacation",
       T6."free_milk",
       T6."early_retirement",
       T6."half_day",
       T6."week_length",
       T6."medical_inspection",
       T6."sout_status",
       T6."sout_required",
       T6."sout_required_comment",
       T6."is_template",
       T6."template_id",
       T6."staff_position_id",
       T6."night_shift",
       T6."health_food",
       T6."shift_duration",
       T6."condition_class",
       T6."workplace_status",
       T6."workplace_status_comment",
       T6."surcharge",
       T6."extra_vacation",
       T6."occupational_disease",
       T6."medical_inspection_period",
       T6."preferential_pension_provision",
       T6."card_number",
       T6."sanitary_standard",
       T6."pregnant_woman",
       T6."link_id",
       T6."similar_to_id",
       T6."metadata",
       T6."latest_risk_project_id",
       T6."latest_sout_report_id",
       "enterprise_staffposition"."id",
       "enterprise_staffposition"."created",
       "enterprise_staffposition"."modified",
       "enterprise_staffposition"."is_active",
       "enterprise_staffposition"."safe_deleted_by_id",
       "enterprise_staffposition"."safe_deleted_at",
       "enterprise_staffposition"."owner_id",
       "enterprise_staffposition"."created_by_id",
       "enterprise_staffposition"."updated_by_id",
       "enterprise_staffposition"."name",
       "enterprise_staffposition"."subunit_id",
       "enterprise_staffposition"."profession_id",
       "enterprise_staffposition"."wage_fund",
       "risk_riskworkplace"."id",
       "risk_riskworkplace"."created",
       "risk_riskworkplace"."modified",
       "risk_riskworkplace"."is_active",
       "risk_riskworkplace"."safe_deleted_by_id",
       "risk_riskworkplace"."safe_deleted_at",
       "risk_riskworkplace"."owner_id",
       "risk_riskworkplace"."created_by_id",
       "risk_riskworkplace"."updated_by_id",
       "risk_riskworkplace"."workplace_id"
FROM "enterprise_workplace"
         INNER JOIN "enterprise_project" ON ("enterprise_workplace"."project_id" = "enterprise_project"."id")
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "classifier_profession"
                         ON ("enterprise_workplace"."profession_id" = "classifier_profession"."id")
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "enterprise_subunit" ON ("enterprise_workplace"."subunit_id" = "enterprise_subunit"."id")
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "enterprise_organization"
                         ON ("enterprise_subunit"."organization_id" = "enterprise_organization"."id")
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "enterprise_workplace" T6 ON ("enterprise_workplace"."template_id" = T6."id")
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "enterprise_staffposition"
                         ON ("enterprise_workplace"."staff_position_id" = "enterprise_staffposition"."id")
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "risk_riskworkplace" ON ("enterprise_workplace"."id" = "risk_riskworkplace"."workplace_id")
WHERE ("enterprise_workplace"."is_active")
ORDER BY (REGEXP_MATCHES(
        CASE WHEN ("enterprise_workplace"."number" IS NULL) THEN '0' ELSE "enterprise_workplace"."number" END,
        '\d+'))::int[] ASC, (regexp_matches(CASE
                                                WHEN ("enterprise_workplace"."number" IS NULL) THEN '0'
                                                ELSE "enterprise_workplace"."number" END, '\D+'))::char[] ASC
```

Select was auto-generated by django, for this reason too many fields returns.

It runs on 13.4 if I reduce fields that returns count to ±150. Fields that i remove from select is random - only count. I tried many different variations and only on ±150 it works.

Does anyone know what postgres changes from 11.3 to 13.4 may cause this error?

Comment: I can't reproduce it.  But I tried on 13.5, not 13.4.  If all the tables are empty, do you still get the error?